# I want to return my computer to factory settings from Windows. ¿How do I uninstall Ubuntu to avoid any conflict?

Tags: uninstall, settings

As maybe we all know, Windows gets slower with the time, (it doesn't happen in Ubuntu) and due to this I want to 'restart' my laptop, from Windows to the default settings when it was new, using the backup software  that my laptop include. I have done that before I installed Ubuntu, but now I think doing it will arise some conflicts due to the partitions. So first,  I want to uninstall Ubuntu, (which in fact is a little untidy because it was the first time I installed it and I use it to experiment, for example I didn't install the Home folder in another partition), then restart the laptop with default factory settings to fix Windows, and then install Ubuntu again.

So, it is necessary to uninstall Ubuntu before I return my laptop to factory settings?
If it is necessary, how do I uninstall it properly?

Is there any way to only reinstall Ubuntu without affecting Windows?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Ubuntu using Wubi.exe ? or did you use a bootable medium ? 
-- If it is by using wubi.exe; you can definitely uninstall Ubuntu and start over. If you installed it in another partition using bootable medium, you might want to 
(i) format that partition and reinstall it using a bootable medium (OR)
(ii)In case you do not want to format the partition --> Insert the bootable medium containing the version of Ubuntu that you want to install and boot from it, and select "Reinstall Ubuntu XX.XX" after selecting "Install Ubuntu"(instead of "Try Ubuntu").

Answer (score 0):

No, you have not remove ubuntu. in windows recovery, system remove everthing include windows own patitation. after create everthing, patitations, filetables. like a fresh format. so you do not need remove ubuntu. it will automaticly.